# Why are my PHP session variables not working?

Tags: php, session

All of a sudden, my PHP session variables stopped being stored. Previously, it worked fine but without any noticeable changes, the variables aren't being stored anymore.

I tried using code on adminlogin.php to display all the existing session variables, and indeed, they weren't being stored when the login form is used. Once the page is reloaded, they aren't stored anymore.

I also made a new file, random.php, in which I stored a random number to $_SESSION['Number']. After doing that, I went back to adminlogin.php, filled in the form on that page, and reloaded the page. Once again, the session variables that the form was supposed to store aren't in the session array, but the random number $_SESSION['Number'] was displayed.

connect.php (header)

```
<?php 

session_start();

$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'sharkcard';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 3306;

$link = mysqli_init();
$connection = new mysqli(

   $host, 
   $user, 
   $password, 
   $db
);

if(!(empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn'])) && !empty($_SESSION['StudentID']))
{
    $loggedin = 1;
}
else{
    $loggedin = 0;
}


?>
```

adminlogin.php

```
<?php include 'connect.php';
    if($_SESSION['LoggedIn'] == 1)
{
        echo "Welcome back! You are: " . $_SESSION['StudentID'] . " " . $_SESSION['Row']['FirstName'] . " " . $_SESSION['Row']['LastName'] . "<br>";
    }

else{

if(!($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")){
?>

<form action="adminlogin.php" method="POST">
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" autofocus="autofocus"><br>
    sharkcard ID: <input type="text" name="id"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
}

else if(empty($_POST['id']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
    echo "You left something blank! Reload the page and try again.";
}

else {

    $id = ($_POST['id']);
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $checklogin = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE StudentID = '".$id."' AND AdminPassword = '".$password."' AND AdminPrivileges = 1");
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($checklogin);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($checklogin);

        $_SESSION['StudentID'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['Row'] = $row; // added
        $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;


        echo "<h1><font color=\"green\">Success</font></h1>";

        echo "<b>Account Information</b><br>" . $_SESSION['StudentID'] . " " . $_SESSION['Row']['FirstName'] . " ". $_SESSION['Row']['LastName'];

    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h1><font color=\"red\">Failure</font></h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, your account could not be found. Please reload and try again.</a>.</p>";
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you using MD5 to store passwords with? I hope you're not going live with this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is line 2 of adminlogin.php
 `if($_SESSION['LoggedIn'] == 1)`
should be `if($loggedin)`

Also `$_SESSION['LoggedIn']` and `$_SESSION['StudentID']` are not arrays so you should use `isset()` not `empty()` in connect.php on line 19.